# Can't delete a post in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on the user posting aspect of my website, here is an example mongoose  query where I am trying to delete a post:

```
mongoose.model('users').findOne({ _id: req.user._id }, function(err, user){
            if(err) console.log("ERROR: ", err);

            for(var i = 0, length = user.posts.length; i < length; i++){
                var post = user.posts[i],
                    index = i;

                console.log("User Post: ", post);
                console.log("User INDEX: ", index);

                if(post == req.params.postid){
                    console.log("USER POSTS BEFORE: ", user.posts);
                    delete user.posts[index];
                    user.posts = user.posts.filter(function(value){ return value ? true : false; });

                    if(postCount > 3) user.posts.push(latestPost.postid);
                }
            }
            console.log("USER POSTS AFTER: ", user.posts);
            user.save();
        });
```

It looks like the problem exists here:

```
delete user.posts[index];
user.posts = user.posts.filter(function(value){ return value ? true : false; });
```

the console.log's even return success:

```
USER POSTS BEFORE:  ["55bd150c13287825380d6476","55bd151413287825380d6479"]
USER POSTS AFTER:  ["55bd150c13287825380d6476"]
```

it seems if I were to just do this

```
delete user.posts[index];
user.posts = user.posts
```

it will work, however I will have one of the values as null, and I don't want this.

I have also tried using jresigs .remove on the array prototype, and this does not work either..

```
// Array Remove - By John Resig (MIT Licensed)
    Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
      var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
      this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
      return this.push.apply(this, rest);
    };
```

Oddly enough, when I try these things on jsfiddle they work fine, it is just here within expressJS that I am getting the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
delete user.posts[index];
```

With [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
user.posts.splice(index, 1);
```

This will actually remove the entry from the array and not set it to null/undefined like delete does.